# spy on setTimeout, but it's not to be called as expected

Tags: typescript, jestjs, settimeout

Code here:

`index.ts`:

```
export function main() {
  const timer = setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('teresa teng');
    clearTimeout(timer);
  }, 100);
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```
import { main } from '.';

describe('test suites', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.useRealTimers();
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
  it('should pass', () => {
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    const setTimeoutSpy = jest.spyOn(global, 'setTimeout');
    main();
    expect(setTimeoutSpy).toBeCalledWith(expect.any(Function), 100);
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(100);
    expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith('teresa teng');
  });

  it('should pass too', () => {
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    // order matters?
    const setTimeoutSpy = jest.spyOn(global, 'setTimeout');
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    main();
    expect(setTimeoutSpy).toBeCalledWith(expect.any(Function), 100);
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(100);
    expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith('teresa teng');
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 FAIL  issues/spy-setTimeout-useFakeTimers/index.test.ts
  test suites
    ✓ should pass (17 ms)
    ✕ should pass too (2 ms)

  ● test suites › should pass too

    expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalledWith(...expected)

    Expected: Any<Function>, 100

    Number of calls: 0

      21 |     jest.useFakeTimers();
      22 |     main();
    > 23 |     expect(setTimeoutSpy).toBeCalledWith(expect.any(Function), 100);
         |                           ^
      24 |     jest.advanceTimersByTime(100);
      25 |     expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith('teresa teng');
      26 |   });

      at Object.<anonymous> (issues/spy-setTimeout-useFakeTimers/index.test.ts:23:27)

  console.log
    teresa teng

      at console.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:845:25)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.297 s
```

The only difference between the two test case codes is the order of the `jest.useFakeTimers()` statement and the `jest.spyOn(global, 'setTimeout')` statement.

What caused the second test case to fail? I expect both of them should pass.

Comment: I think the issue is the spy call, rater than the order of the two. [The documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks) says that `useFakeTimers` mocks all timers. It then lists examples directly using `expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenCalled...`. If you spy on the pre-mocked function, it's not going to be called after it's replaced with a mock.

Comment: @VLAZ I have the same idea as you. It seems I spy on the pre-mocked `setTimeout` function. I remember spying on a method twice will throw an error. Maybe `useFakeTimers` does not spy `setTimeout` internally

Comment: No, spying twice won't throw an error. Fake timers have no other way to work without replacing async API like setTimeout, etc, that's what they they do.

Comment: @EstusFlask Sorry, I made a mistake, I remember it as sinon.stub's behavior

Comment: Why are you spying on `setTimeout` at all? The *behaviour* is that a value gets logged after 100ms, the fact that `setTimeout` is called with a function and the value `100` is an implementation detail.